Fedora Kinoite server freeze issues
I am trying to run a server on an InFocus Kangaroo, which is a somewhat old PC from 2016 with sup-par hardware specs (2GB RAM and an Intel Atom). I initially tried running it on Ubuntu desktop (I'm too new to Linux to comfortably use server/core), which barely worked. I wouldn't even be able to make it past the setup menu before the PC froze and became unresponsive. As per my friend's recommendation, I gave up on Ubuntu and tried Fedora Kinoite (Stable Fedora build with KDE Plasma). This was quite a bit more successful, and I was able to install the OS and start using it as a normal PC. However, it would eventually become unresponsive at random times. Sometimes it would freeze when I connected to a Wi-Fi network and then recover, but eventually it would hit a permanent freeze (I once left the computer open overnight and it was still unresponsive in the morning). From what I can recall, these freezes would often happen while I was browsing the web (possibly when opening new pages) or going through menus, although there was no clear pattern.
So far, I have only tried "watch -n 0.2 free -m", but I didn't notice a distinct drop in free memory before the system froze.
Are there any commands I should run to try and figure out this issue?

On Server Fault, how does this professional IT? Replace it with supported hardware. I vote to move to Super User.

It runs an OEM Windows 10 fine - there must be a way to make it run Linux without freezing right?
